# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my Forum project. So I created a table called `answers`, and here is the Migration for that:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('answer');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('question_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And then in order to make relation between `Question` Model & `Answer` Model, I added these:

**Question.php:**

```
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

**User.php:**

```
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

After that, I added this for showing the question information:

```
@foreach($show->answers as $ans)
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-lg">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">Answer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right">
                <div><span>Writer: </span><a href="">{{ $ans->id->name }}</a></div>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
                <p>
                    {{ $ans->answer }}
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
 @endforeach
```

But now I get this error:

**ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

So what is going wrong here? How can I properly return the name of user who asked a question?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this,

Thanks.

**UPDATE #1:**

[image: CAPTURE]

**UPDATE #2:**

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['answer', 'user_id', 'question_id'];

}
```

Comment: @u_mulder I tried that and got *Null* result

Comment: what is the relation name between answer and user model? is it 'user'?

Comment: @OMR At the `User.php` I named `answers()`. And  `Answer.php` holds only *fillable* variable.

Comment: `$ans->id->name`? Didn't you meant something like `$ans->user->name`?

Comment: @u_mulder No there is no field named `name` at `answers` table. I just added a picture of my table. Check it out plz.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Still get the `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object ` error

Comment: @u_mulder I want to get user name of user from `users` table based on his `user_id` from answers table

Comment: You should show your models and tell us how users and answers are linked.

Comment: please share the whole Answer model

Comment: @OMR I just added it, plz check out **UPDATE #2**  & thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should build the relation between Answer an User models in Answer model:

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['answer', 'user_id', 'question_id'];

   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

  public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

and in your blade, assuming that the $ans is an instance of Answer model, you can use:

```
{{ $ans->user->name }}
```

Comment: Thank u man, you don't how much you helped me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I rollbacked the Migration and used this but still get the error! `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('answer');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: you can erase $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); and $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');